# Can I beat Journey without using the jump button?

Tags: journey

I've been trying to play through Journey without jumping (just for the fun of it). But thanks to a couple of problem areas, this seems like an impossible goal.

The first problem are is

> the glowing tower. Two sections of it, actually. First, the second section, with the jellyfish. I haven't found a way to get to them without jumping myself. The scond is the fourth section, with the bridges. Again, getting to them is the problem.

The second problem is at the

> the snowy part of the mountain, after the searchlight section, where you need to rise up using the cloths. In previous sections you can sort of wiggle your way up these kinds of things once they hold you afloat. But here, they can't keep you floating.

Is there some way to pass these sections without using the jump button?

Comment: I seriously doubt this is possible. What about the ending segment where you have to float?

Comment: You'd be surprised how many things actually boost you upwards. Or how often you can find the little flying ribbons that you can call to give you a lift. And then call again to give you a lift even further.

Comment: Not sure about your query, but I was hoping you could help me with this - I've been trying to get through the original Doom without using the Shoot button. Is this possible?

Comment: @Alex I haven't tried myself, but I'm guessing you can get through just fine by shooting nothing but the bosses. I belive those are the only things that you're actually required to kill (and no, you can't get Cyberdemon to kill itself with its own rockets because it takes no splas damage from explotions). Killing anything else just makes your life easier. Sure, you'll propably need to memorize the level layouts, health and armor locations and maybe do some luring to clear out some narrow corridors, but hey, that's why this kind of challenges are so fun :)

Comment: @DJPirtu Damn...I wasn't actually expecting a coherent, useful answer :P

Comment: @Alex and DJ - would you mind moving your question and answer into a separate question? It will be more appropriate than in comments... plus, it will generate you both some rep :)

Comment: @Oak It was actually just meant to be a joke - 'how do I play X without using the single most important function in the game?', but DJ Pirtu went and ruined it by giving me a reasonable answer :D

Comment: @Alex Wow. Someone actually managed to figure out how to beat Doom without firing a shot. Including all the bosses: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o78DzBJ4Rv8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive trials and some people from the [offical forums](http://www.thatgamecompany.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2106) trying to same, I will now conclude that the answer is:
**No.**

There is a certain minimun of jumps required to beat the game (around 5, I'd guess).